# Composer failed to install dependencies in composer.json file when launching environment in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to deploy an existing PHP application in Elastic Beanstalk, but when I try to deploy it the same error keeps getting returned:

> Instance deployment failed to install Composer dependencies specified in 'composer.json' in your source bundle. The deployment failed.

Below is the composer.json file of the application:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^0.6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.65",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.15",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.8",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I'm not sure if this is down to incompatibility (the existing environment uses PHP 7, whereas this uses PHP 8) or another issue that I haven't thought of. The server is running PHP 8.1 on the Amazon Linux 2 operating system.

Edit: I found the `eb-engine.log` file and found the error that is causing the problem. I'm not sure how to solve it, since I suspect this is a process that is automatically executed by Elastic Beanstalk.

> An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Install composer dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: installing
> composer dependencies failed with error: Command /bin/sh -c composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction  failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Do not run Composer a
> s root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.ebextension` configurations to install composer for your projects deployed using elastic beanstalk.
create a directory named .ebextension and place a file `composer.config` inside `.ebextension`. Do paste the following code:

```
commands:
  01-install-composer:
    command: "export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update --2"

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root

container_commands:
  01-optimize:
    command: "/usr/bin/composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize"
```

Comment: While it might be certainly true that this can be used, in which regard is this - in your very humble opinion - worth to remark in context of the question if I may ask? Please feel free to add those clarifications to your answer by editing it. BTW, do you know where to obtain the actual logging when configuring as you suggest in your answer? Just in case if the OP was still not able to obtain the information with the default configuration -- and for which you certainly know as well, right?

Comment: I tried following these instructions and after committing these changes to my Git repository, the error still persists.

Comment: I found the error that's been causing the problem, but I'm not sure how to resolve it - I've put it in the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!